# "Content Publishing has change.." message when assigning a custom content type to a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, document-library, content-type

Inside our SharePoint online site collection >> i created a custom content type named "DC" which has the built-in document content type as its parent. then i went to our document library as usual >> enable content type management >> assign the newly created content type to the library. but i got this new message, which i were not getting before:-

[image]

so what this message is trying to say ? and is my above steps of assigning a custom content type to our document library still valid? or things have recently changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In September 2021, Microsoft changed content type publishing working mechanism to improve performance and make newly published and updated content types available to sites faster. This message is just a notice to end users. you can ignore it.

Now there is also a new way to add published content types directly to a list or library. I have listed detailed steps in my answer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/648314/34content-publishing-has-change34-message-when-ass.html?childToView=648463#answer-648463.

Reference: [What’s changed in content type publishing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-s-changed-in-content-type-publishing-609399c7-5c42-4e25-aff0-b59d4aa1867f).

Comment: thanks for your reply,, so this message is concerning the Content Type Publishing syndication site? and not the content type define on the site level? am i correct?